# Error en la creación de comentarios en asociaciones polimorficas

Tags: html5, css3, ruby-on-rails, ruby, polimorfismo

Tengo problemas para poder **crear comentarios de respuestas**. Estoy usando asociaciones *polimorficas*. El programa me deja crear comentarios de preguntas pero no me permite crear comentarios de respuestas.

Es de anotar de que los comentarios de las respuestas dependen de una pregunta.

#### Rutas

routes.rb:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users
  resources :comments

  resources :questions do
   resources :answers, except: [:show] do
     resources :comments, except: [:show], module: :answers
     resources :votes, only:[:create,:update, :destroy], module: :answers
   end

   resources :votes, only:[:create,:update, :destroy], module: :questions
   resources :comments, except: [:show], module: :questions
 end

  root 'questions#index'
end
```

#### Modelos

answer.rb:

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: answers
#
#  id          :integer          not null, primary key
#  body        :text
#  user_id     :integer
#  question_id :integer
#  created_at  :datetime         not null
#  updated_at  :datetime         not null
#

class Answer < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :comments
  has_many :comments, as: :commentable
  has_many :votes, as: :voteable
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :question

  validates :body, presence: true
end
```

comment.rb:

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: comments
#
#  id               :integer          not null, primary key
#  commentable_type :string
#  commentable_id   :integer
#  body             :text
#  created_at       :datetime         not null
#  updated_at       :datetime         not null
#  user_id          :integer
#

class Comment < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :commentable, polymorphic: true
  belongs_to :user

  validates :body, presence: true
end
```

question.rb:

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: questions
#
#  id         :integer          not null, primary key
#  title      :string
#  body       :text
#  user_id    :integer
#  created_at :datetime         not null
#  updated_at :datetime         not null
#

class Question < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :comments, as: :commentable
  has_many :votes, as: :voteable
  has_many :answers
  belongs_to :user

  validates :title, presence: true
  validates :body, presence: true
end
```

user.rb:

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: users
#
#  id                     :integer          not null, primary key
#  email                  :string           default(""), not null
#  encrypted_password     :string           default(""), not null
#  reset_password_token   :string
#  reset_password_sent_at :datetime
#  remember_created_at    :datetime
#  sign_in_count          :integer          default(0), not null
#  current_sign_in_at     :datetime
#  last_sign_in_at        :datetime
#  current_sign_in_ip     :string
#  last_sign_in_ip        :string
#  created_at             :datetime         not null
#  updated_at             :datetime         not null
#  fullname               :string
#

class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :questions
  has_many :answers
  has_many :comments
  has_many :comments, as: :commentable
  has_many :votes, as: :voteable


  validates :fullname, presence: true
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
end
```

vote.rb:

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: votes
#
#  id            :integer          not null, primary key
#  voteable_id   :integer
#  voteable_type :string
#  created_at    :datetime         not null
#  updated_at    :datetime         not null
#  user_id       :integer
#

class Vote < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :voteable, polymorphic: true
  belongs_to :user

  def  self.voted_by?(user, voteable)
    voteable.votes.find_by(user_id: user.id)
  end
end
```

#### Controladores

answers/comments_controller.rb:

```
class Answers::CommentsController < CommentsController
  before_action :set_commentable

  def create
    super
  end

  private

    def set_commentable
      @commentable = Answer.find(params[:answer_id])
    end
end
```

answers/votes_controller.rb:

```
class Answers::VotesController < VotesController
  before_action :set_voteable

  private

    def set_voteable
      @voteable = Answer.find(params[:answer_id])
    end
end
```

questions/comments_controller.rb:

```
class Questions::CommentsController < CommentsController
  before_action :set_commentable

  private

    def set_commentable
      @commentable = Question.find(params[:question_id])
    end
end
```

questions/votes_controller.rb:

```
class Questions::VotesController < VotesController
  before_action :set_voteable

  private

    def set_voteable
      @voteable = Question.find(params[:question_id])
    end
end
```

answers_controllers.rb:

```
class AnswersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:index, :show]
  before_action :find_answer, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :current_question, only: [:show, :create]

  def new
    @answer = @question.answers.build
    render :layout => false
  end

  def create
    @answer = @question.answers.build(answer_params)
    @answer.user = current_user

    if @answer.save
      redirect_to question_path(@question), notice: 'Answer saved...'
    else
      flash[:alert] = 'Something went wrong...'
      redirect_to question_path(@question)
    end
  end

  private

    def answer_params
      params.require(:answer).permit(:body)
    end

    def find_answer
      @answer = Answer.find(params[:id])
    end

    def current_question
      @question = Question.find(params[:question_id])
    end
end
```

comments_controller.rb:

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @comment = @commentable.comments.new(comment_params)
    @comment.user = current_user

    if @commentable.save
      redirect_to @commentable, notice: "Your comments was successfully posted..."
    end
  end

  private

    def comment_params
      params.require(:comment).permit(:body)
    end
end
```

questions_controller.rb:

```
class QuestionsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:index, :show]
  before_action :find_question, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def index
    @questions = Question.all

    if params[:title].present?
      @questions = @questions.where("title LIKE ?", "%#{params[:title].capitalize}%").page(params[:page]).per(4)
    else
      @questions = Question.all.order("created_at DESC").page(params[:page]).per(4)
    end
  end

  def new
    @question = Question.new
  end

  def create
    @question = Question.new(question_params)
    @question.user = current_user

    if @question.save
      redirect_to root_path, notice: 'Question saved...'
    else
      flash.now[:alert] = 'Something went wrong...'
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def show
    @found_question = find_question.id
    @answers_question = Answer.where("question_id = ?", @found_question)
  end

  protected

    def record_not_found
      flash[:alert] = "The question was not found..."
      redirect_to root_path
    end

  private

    def question_params
      params.require(:question).permit(:title, :body, :user_id)
    end

    def find_question
      @question = Question.find(params[:id])
    end
end
```

votes_controller.rb:

```
class VotesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  before_action :set_voteable, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def create
    @voteable.votes.create(user: current_user)
    redirect_to question_path(@voteable), notice: "A successfully voted for the question..."
  end

  def destroy
    @voteable.votes.where(user: current_user).take.try(:destroy)
    redirect_to question_path(@voteable), notice: "Successfully removed question vote"
  end
end
```

#### Vistas

answers/_forms.html.erb:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-7 col-sm-offset-1">
     <%= form_for :answer, url: question_answers_path(question.id) do |f| %>
      <div class="form-group mkdown_answer">
         <%= md_simple_editor  do %>
            <%= f.text_area :body, autofocus: true, :rows => 6, style: 'width:100%;', placeholder: "Answer", class: "form-control" %>
         <% end %>
      </div>
      <div class="actions mkdown_button">
        <%= f.submit "Send answer", class: "btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" %>
      </div>
    <% end %>
    <div/>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

comments/_forms.html.erb:

```
<% unless commentable.nil? %>
  <% commentable.comments.each do |comment| %>
    <hr>
    <p>
      <%= comment.body %>
    </p>
  <% end %>
<% end %>

<% unless commentable.nil? %>
  <% commentable.comments.each do |comment| %>
    <hr>
    <p>
      <%= comment.body %>
    </p>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

questions/_forms.html.erb:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-5 col-md-offset-3">

      <h2 class="text-center">Post a question</h2>
      <br/>

      <%= form_for @question do |f| %>
           <%= render "shared/message" %>

        <div class="form-group">
          <%= f.text_field :title, autofocus: true, placeholder: "Title", class: "form-control" %>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
           <%= md_simple_editor  do %>
              <%= f.text_area :body, autofocus: true, :rows => 6, style: 'width:100%;', placeholder: "Description", class: "form-control" %>
           <% end %>    
        </div>

        <div class="actions">
          <%= f.submit "¡Ask!", class: "btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" %>
        </div>
      <% end %>

    <div/>
  </div>
</div>
```

questions/_index.html.erb:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1">
      <h1>Questions</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class= "questions"> <!-- begin questions-->
     <div class="row">
          <div class="question clearfix">
              <div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1 button-ask-question">
                <div class="button-ask-question">
                  <%=  link_to "Ask a question", new_question_path, :method => :get, class: "btn btn-primary" %>
                </div>
              </div>
          </div>
     </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1"> <!-- begin col-sm-10-->
      <hr>
        <% unless @questions.nil? %>
            <% @questions.each do |question| %>
               <div class="question-details">
                <div class="row"> <!-- begin row -->
                  <div class="col-sm-1 data"><!-- begin col-1-->
                    <span><%= question.votes.count  %></span>
                    <span><h5 class="data-label">Votes</h5></span>
                  </div> <!-- end col-1-->
                  <div class="col-sm-1 data"><!-- begin col-2-->
                    <span><span><%= question.answers.count  %></span></span>
                    <span><h5 class="data-label">Answers</h5></span>
                  </div> <!-- end col.2-->
                  <div class="col-sm-10"> <!-- begin cols-2-->
                    <h2 class="question-title"><%= link_to question.title, question %></h2>
                      Asked: <%= question.user.fullname %> <%= time_ago_in_words(question.created_at) %>
                  </div><!-- end cols-3-->
                </div>  <!-- end row -->
               </div>
               <hr>
            <% end %>
            <%= paginate(@questions) %>
        <% end %>
        <br>
      </div> <!-- end col-sm-10-->
    </div>
  </div> <!-- end questions-->
  <br>
</div>
```

questions/show.html.erb:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-1">
            <h2 class="title-question"><%= @question.title %></h2>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="questions">
        <%  unless user_signed_in? %>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-1 col-sm-offset-1">
                <div class="question-upvote upvote-active">
                    <span class="upvote-arrow"></span>
                    <span class="upvote-count">
                        <%= @question.votes.count %>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-8 body-show-question">
                <span>
                    <%= markdown(@question.body) %>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-1 col-sm-offset-1"></div>
            <div class="col-sm-8 comments_signout">
                <span class="comments">
                    <%= render partial: "comments/comments", locals: {commentable: @question} %>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    <% else %>
        <% vote = Vote.voted_by?(current_user,  @question) %>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-1 col-sm-offset-1">
            <% if vote %>
                <%= link_to question_vote_path(@question, vote), method: :delete, class: "question-upvote upvote-active" do %>
                <span class="upvote-arrow"></span>
                <span class="upvote-count"><%= @question.votes.count %></span>
                <% end %>
            <% else %>
                <%= link_to question_votes_path(@question), method: :post, class: "question-upvote" do %>
                <span class="upvote-arrow"></span>
                <span class="upvote-count"><%= @question.votes.count %></span>
                <% end %>
            <% end %>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-8 body-show-question">
                <span> <%= markdown(@question.body) %> </span>
                <span class="comments">
                    <%= render partial: "comments/comments", locals: {commentable: @question} %>
                </span>
                <%= render partial: "comments/form", locals: {commentable: @question} %>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-2"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-1">
                <div>
                    <h2>(<%= @question.answers.count %>) Respuesta(s)</h2>
                </div>
                <%  @answers_question.each do |aq| %>
                <div class="body-answer">
                    <span> <%= markdown(aq.body) %> </span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-comments-answer">
                    <span>
                        <%= render partial: "comments/form", locals: {commentable: @answer} %>
                    </span>
                </div>

                <% end %>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-1">
                <span class="">
                    <%= render partial: "comments/comments", locals: {commentable: @answer} %>
                </span>
                <br>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-1"></div>
            <div class="col-sm-3"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-1">
                <%= render partial: "answers/form", locals: {question: @question} %>
            </div>
        </div>
        <% end %>

    </div>
    <!-- end questions -->
</div>
```

#### Error

[image: Ingreso del comentario para la respuesta]

[image: Error que despliega el sistema]

Comment: No es necesario que pongas el código completo de tu aplicación, de hecho es mejor agregar únicamente el código asociado al error, en este caso sería el código del archivo *comments_controller.rn*, el cual está claramente identificado en la pantalla de error. De esta forma será más amigable para los lectores, evitándoles buscar la línea en todo el código compartido.

Comment: debes de definir la variable `@commentable`, puedes guiarte también con esto: [asociaciones polimórficas](https://gorails.com/episodes/comments-with-polymorphic-associations?autoplay=1) para entender un poco mejor como hacer la relación.

Comment: Gracias, Gerry por su observación, la tendre en cuenta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error se debe a que no estás definiendo la variable `@commentable` dentro del controlador `CommentsController`; mira el código:

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @comment = @commentable.comments.new(comment_params)  # El error está aquí
    @comment.user = current_user

    if @commentable.save
      redirect_to @commentable, notice: "Your comments was successfully posted..."
    end
  end

  private

    def comment_params
      params.require(:comment).permit(:body)
    end
end
```

En la línea que indica el error, estás llamando el método `comments` en una variable (i.e. `@commentable`) no definida, la cual regresa valor `nil`; de ahí el error que diga (traducido):

> método `comments' no definido para nil:NilClass

Esto se debe a que la variable la defines `@commentable` en los controladores que hereda, es decir `Questions::CommentsController` y `Answers::CommentsController`, utilizando `before_action :set_commentable`; sin embargo, en el primero (el de `Questions`) no tienes acción `create` definida, por lo que el método `set_commentable` nunca se ejecuta y la variable `@commentable` no es creada.

En cambio, en el de `Answers` si tienes la acción `create` definida y, por ende, crea la variable `@commentable` antes de llamar al método `create` del controlador padre (`CommentsController`) a través de `super`.

Entonces, debes agregar el método `create` en `Questions::CommentsController` de la misma forma que lo haces en `Answers::CommentsController`:

```
class Questions::CommentsController < CommentsController
  before_action :set_commentable

  def create
   super
  end

  private

    def set_commentable
      @commentable = Question.find(params[:question_id])
    end
end
```

**La modificación que había propuesto anteriormente (i.e. agregar `before_action :set_commentable` en el controlador `CommentsController`) debe ser ignorada y sustituida por esta solución.**

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67621/discussion-on-answer-by-gerry-error-en-la-creacion-de-comentarios-en-asociacione).