# Error al votar respuesta en modelo con polimorfismo

Tags: ruby-on-rails, polimorfismo

Tengo el siguiente modelo que permite votar por questions y por answers teniendo definido el modelo `Vote` como un modelo polimórfico.

La parte de votos de preguntas me funciona correctamente pero no se como abordar la votación para las respuestas.

Las respuestas dependen de una pregunta, y la parte de votación de preguntas me funciona correctamente. ¿Cómo puedo implementar la votación de la pregunta en la vista `show`?

vote.rb

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: votes
#
#  id            :integer          not null, primary key
#  voteable_id   :integer
#  voteable_type :string
#  created_at    :datetime         not null
#  updated_at    :datetime         not null
#  user_id       :integer
#

class Vote < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :voteable, polymorphic: true
  belongs_to :user

  def  self.voted_by?(user, voteable)
    voteable.votes.find_by(user_id: user.id)
  end
end
```

routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users
  resources :comments

  resources :questions do
    resources :answers, except: [:show] do
      resources :comments, except: [:show], module: :answers
      resources :votes, only:[:create,:update, :destroy], module: :answers
    end
    resources :votes, only:[:create,:update, :destroy], module: :questions
    resources :comments, except: [:show], module: :questions
  end

  root 'questions#index'
end
```

Vista *show.html.erb* del modelo `Question` donde se despliega toda la información relacionada con `questions`, `answers` y `votes` y donde  debo de hacer una implementación similar a lo que hago con los `votes` de las `questions`.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-1">
            <h2 class="title-question"><%= @question.title %></h2>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="questions">
        <% if user_signed_in? %>
        <div class="row">
              <div class="col-sm-1 col-sm-offset-1">
                    <% vote = Vote.voted_by?(current_user,  @question) %>
                <% if vote %>
                      <%= link_to question_vote_path(@question, vote), method: :delete, class: "question-upvote upvote-active" do %>
                          <span class="upvote-arrow"></span>
                          <span class="upvote-count"><%= @question.votes.count %></span>
                      <% end %>
                <% else %>
                    <%= link_to question_votes_path(@question), method: :post, class: "question-upvote" do %>
                            <span class="upvote-arrow"></span>
                        <span class="upvote-count"><%= @question.votes.count %></span>
                    <% end %>
                <% end %>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-8 body-show-question">
                    <span> <%= markdown(@question.body) %> </span>
                    <span class="comments">
                        <%= render partial: "comments/comments", locals: {commentable: @question} %>
                    </span>
                    <%= render partial: "comments/form", locals: {commentable: [@question]} %>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-1">
                    <div>
                        <h2>(<%= @question.answers.count %>) Respuesta(s)</h2>
                    </div>

                    <% @question.answers.each do |answer|  %>
                    <div class="row">
                      <div class="col-sm-1 col-sm-offset-1">
                            <% vote = Vote.voted_by?(current_user, answer) %>
                        <% if vote %>
                              <%= link_to question_answer_vote_path(@question, answer), method: :delete, class: "question-upvote upvote-active" do %>
                                  <span class="upvote-arrow"></span>
                                  <span class="upvote-count"><%=answer.votes.count %></span>
                              <% end %>
                        <% else %>
                            <%= link_to question_answer_votes_path(@question, answer, vote), method: :post, class: "question-upvote" do %>
                                    <span class="upvote-arrow"></span>
                            <% end %>
                        <% end %>
                        </div>

                    <div class="body-answer">
                            <span> <%= markdown(answer.body) %> </span>
                                <%= render partial: "comments/comments", locals: {commentable: answer} %>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-comments-answer">
                            <span>
                                <%= render partial: "comments/form", locals: {commentable: [answer.question, answer]} %>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                    <% end %>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-1">
                    <%= render partial: "answers/form", locals: {question: @question} %>
                </div>
            </div>
        <% else %>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-1 col-sm-offset-1">
                    <div class="question-upvote">
                        <span class="upvote-arrow"></span>
                        <span class="upvote-count"><%= @question.votes.count %></span>
                    </div>
              </div>
            <div class="col-sm-8 body-show-question">
                <span> <%= markdown(@question.body) %> </span>
                <span class="comments">
                    <%= render partial: "comments/comments", locals: {commentable: @question} %>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-1">
                <div>
                    <h2>(<%= @question.answers.count %>) Respuesta(s)</h2>
                </div>
                <% @question.answers.each do |answer|  %>
                    <div class="body-answer">
                        <span> <%= markdown(answer.body) %> </span>
                        <%= render partial: "comments/comments", locals: {commentable: answer} %>
                    </div>
                <% end %>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

votes_controller.rb

```
class VotesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  before_action :set_voteable, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def create
    @voteable.votes.create(user: current_user)
    redirect_to question_path(@voteable), notice: "A successfully voted for the question..."
  end

  def destroy
    @voteable.votes.where(user: current_user).take.try(:destroy)
    redirect_to question_path(@voteable), notice: "Successfully removed question vote"
  end
end
```

Comment: La solución es igual que la implementación de `comments` en [tu pregunta anterior](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/111328/error-en-la-creaci%C3%B3n-de-comentarios-en-asociaciones-polimorficas). Te recomiendo que repliques esa funcionalidad (excepto que, en lugar de registrar un comentario, registras el voto, tal como lo haces actualmente con preguntas) y, en caso que tengas algún problema publiques una pregunta más específica.

Comment: @Gerry, de hecho los votos para preguntas me funciona OK, pero no tengo muy claro como pasarle la answer, el repositorio sigue igual, trate de pasarle la answer mediante el objeto del ciclo cuando impirme las respuestas y me generaba error, hice una prueba en otro archivo pero no hice commit.

Comment: ¿Podrías incluir el código del controlador y el error que obtienes con la solución que estás intentando ahora?

Comment: Como puedo enviarle el @answer si esa answer la capturo en un formulario que invoco desde el show? <% vote = Vote.voted_by?(current_user,  @question) %>

Comment: @Gerry, actualicé el repositorio, ahí estan los cambios y este es el errro que despliega:                                                                                                                                   
ActionController::UrlGenerationError at /questions/1

No route matches {:action=>"update", :controller=>"questions/votes", :id=>nil, :question_id=>"1"}, missing required keys: [:id]

Comment: class VotesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  before_action :set_voteable, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def create
    @voteable.votes.create(user: current_user)
    redirect_to question_path(@voteable), notice: "A successfully voted for the question..."
  end

  def destroy
    @voteable.votes.where(user: current_user).take.try(:destroy)
    redirect_to question_path(@voteable), notice: "Successfully removed question vote"
  end

end

Comment: @Gerry, ya agregue el códio de VotesController y actualicé el repositorio.

Comment: ¿@Gerry, como debo manejar los Votes para las answers ya que las answers dependen de las questions o eso debido a las asociaciones tiene itro manejo?. Aún no doy con la solución. El repositorio se encuentra actualizado para que lo pueda revisar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema principal está en los *helpers* de rutas utilizados para aplicar/borrar los votos de las respuestas; en tu código tienes `question_vote_path` y `question_votes_path`, los cuales apuntan a preguntas únicamente, pero tu necesitas que apunten a las respuestas de la pregunta, entonces debes utilizar `question_answer_vote_path` y `question_answer_votes_path` para que funcione.

```
<!-- app/views/questions/show.html.erb (código parcial) -->

<% if vote %>
  <%= link_to question_answer_vote_path(@question, answer), method: :delete, class: "question-upvote upvote-active" do %>
      <span class="upvote-arrow"></span>
      <span class="upvote-count"><%=answer.votes.count %></span>
  <% end %>
<% else %>
    <%= link_to question_answer_votes_path(@question, answer, vote), method: :post, class: "question-upvote" do %>
        <span class="upvote-arrow"></span>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Es importante notar como agregué `@question` a cada ruta para poder identificar la pregunta a la que hace referencia y así tener los parámetros de la ruta completos.

Una vez realizado este cambio, deberás actualizar el controlador `VotesController` para que, al igual que en `CommentsController` puedas obtener el `id` de la pregunta a través de la variable `@votable`, independientemente si esta es un objeto `Question` o uno `Answer`:

```
# app/controllers/votes_controller.rb:

class VotesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  before_action :set_voteable, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def create
    @voteable.votes.create(user: current_user)
    redirect_to question_path(question), notice: "A successfully voted for the question..."
  end

  def destroy
    @voteable.votes.where(user: current_user).take.try(:destroy)
    redirect_to question_path(question), notice: "Successfully removed vote"
  end

  private

    def question
      @voteable.try(:question) || @voteable
    end
end
```

Comment: @GarcíaHenry Te envié un [pull request](https://github.com/henrygarciaospina/stackoverflow/pull/2) con el cambio descrito en la respuesta.

Comment: modificaciones, OK, para camabiar el mensaje debería preguntar por el tipo de voteable?. Ya que en este momento sea pregunta o respuesta genera un mensaje de voto o eliminación de voto de question. O es recomendable usar un mensaje genérico?.

Comment: No hay respuesta correcta, puedes optar por un mensaje genérico o bien uno personalizado (por tipo de `voteable`); si optas por este último, sí podrías preguntar por el tipo de `voteable` para determinar que mensaje poner.